# sqlite window function to get difference and product

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am using a window function to get the difference in the values of a column (downloads) between two dates. I'd also like to get the product of that difference multiplied by the size of the file to get the bytes downloaded for the period.

With the help of this community, I am able to get the number of downloads but cannot find the correct syntax to get the product of downloads * size.

Table 'files'

```
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----------+------------+
|      site     |       full_path        | size | downloads | date_stamp |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----------+------------+
| Lawrenceville | lr1/dir1/subdir1/file1 | 1000 |     7     | 2019-08-08 |
| Lawrenceville | lr1/dir1/subdir1/file1 | 1010 |     9     | 2019-08-15 |
| Lawrenceville | lr1/dir1/subdir1/file2 | 1213 |     5     | 2019-08-08 |
| Lawrenceville | lr1/dir1/subdir1/file2 | 2000 |     5     | 2019-08-15 |
| Lawrenceville | lr1/dir2/subdir1/file1 | 2213 |     5     | 2019-08-15 |
| Rennes        | rr1/dir1/subdir1/file3 | 200  |     3     | 2019-08-08 |
| Rennes        | rr1/dir1/subdir1/file3 | 201  |     4     | 2019-08-15 |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----------+------------+
```

```
SELECT site, sum(diff) FROM (SELECT site, downloads - lag(downloads, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY site, full_path ORDER BY date_stamp) AS diff FROM files WHERE date_stamp IN ('2019-08-15', '2019-08-08')) group by site
```

produces this:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| site          | downloads |
+---------------+-----------+
| Lawrenceville |     2     |
| Rennes        |     1     |
+---------------+-----------+
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT site, sum(diff), sum(sum(diff)*bytes) FROM (SELECT site, downloads - lag(downloads, 1), size OVER (PARTITION BY site, full_path ORDER BY date_stamp) AS diff, bytes FROM files WHERE date_stamp IN ('2019-08-15', '2019-08-08')) group by site

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Ideally I want this output:

```
+---------------+-----------+----------+
| site          | downloads | bytes    |
+---------------+-----------+----------+
| Lawrenceville |     2     | 2020     |
| Rennes        |     1     | 201      |
+---------------+-----------+----------+
```

Lawrenceville had 2 downloads of file lr1/dir1/subdir1/file1 which is 1010 bytes (on 2019-08-15). File lr1/dir1/subdir1/file2 had no downloads for that period. It would be nice to include files lr1/dir1/subdir1/file2 and lr1/dir2/subdir1/file1 but they get excluded by the window function. I can get them with a separate query.

Rennes has 1 download of file rr1/dir1/subdir1/file3

Answer (score 0):

If your current query works then you only need max() window function in the subquery:

```
SELECT site, sum(diff) downloads, sum(diff) * size bytes
FROM (
  SELECT 
    site, 
    downloads - lag(downloads, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY site, full_path ORDER BY date_stamp) AS diff,
    max(size) OVER (PARTITION BY site, full_path) AS size
  FROM files 
  WHERE date_stamp IN ('2019-08-15', '2019-08-08')
) 
group by site
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nAyNJbKn8WDWVjgaN75thL/3).
Results:

```
| site          | downloads | bytes |
| ------------- | --------- | ----- |
| Lawrenceville | 2         | 2020  |
| Rennes        | 1         | 201   |
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the data set I provided but breaks down when I add another row to the data set

Comment: I don't have your data. This code answers the question as you posted it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm trying to show an additional row in the comments without success. If you add a row with these values, the results change:  ```| Rennes        | rr1/dir1/file6         |  1   |     5     | 2019-08-08 |
```

Comment: I would have expected this new row to be excluded from the 'window' because there is not another row with the same site/full_path combination so then there would be no row for 'lag(downloads, 1). That seems to exclude rows as it should where site = 'Lawrenceville"

Comment: The function that I added to your query is max(). You used lag() in the code you already had and posted. I assumed it is working. Isn't it?

Comment: It appeared to be working correctly, yes. Now I'm questioning that. It seems to exclude the file6 row from the window when just counting downloads but when I include max() the result for bytes changes from 201 to 1.

Comment: Then you should go back the your previous question where you got the code and post there this comment.